# Count the account of the files at first and send a different file every minute

Tags: java

I have a folder named collect, there will be some files such as selectData01.json, selectData02.json, selectData03.json and so on.

I have to count the account of the files at first, and then I will send a different file every minute.

Now I want to konw how to achieve the purpose

```
public String getData() {

        String strLocation = new SendSituationData().getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
        log.info("strLocation = ");
//        String strParent = new File(strLocation).getParent() + "/collectData/conf.properties";
//        System.out.println("strParent = " + strParent);

        File fileConf = new File("collect/");
        System.out.println("fileConf = " + fileConf.getAbsolutePath());

        List<List<String>> listFiles = new ArrayList<>();

        //File root  = new File(DashBoardListener.class.getClassLoader().getResource("collectData/").getPath());
        //File root = new File("collectData/application.conf");



        File root  = new File(fileConf.getAbsolutePath());

        System.out.println("root.listFiles( ) = " + root.listFiles( ));
        Arrays
                .stream(Objects.requireNonNull(root.listFiles( )))
                .filter(file -> file.getName().endsWith("json"))
                .map(File::toPath)
                .forEach(path -> {
                    try {
                        //List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(path);
                        //System.out.println("lines = " + lines);
                        List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(path);
                        listFiles.add(lines);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace( );
                    }
                });

        String dataBody = listToString(listFiles.get(0));

        //log.info(dataBody);

        ResultMap result = buildRsult();
        //String jsonString = JSON.toJSONString(result);
}

public static String listToString(List<String> stringList){
        if (stringList == null) {
            return null;
        }

        StringBuilder result=new StringBuilder();
        boolean flag=false;
        for (String string : stringList) {
            if (flag) {
                result.append("");
            }else {
                flag=true;
            }
            result.append(string);
        }
        return result.toString();
    }
```

### supplement

My friend, maybe i don't express my purpose explicitly. If I have three files, I will sent the first file in the 0:00, sent the second file in the 0:01, sent the third file in the 0:03, sent the first file in the 0:04, sent the second file in the 0:05 and so on.

If I have five files, I will sent the first file in the 0:00, sent the second file in the 0:01, sent the third file in the 0:03, sent the fourth file in the 0:04, sent the fifth file in the 0:05 and so on.

I want to know how to achieve the function

### supplement

I have a struct Project that contains a folder named `collect`. Each file represents a string.

At first, I want to calculate the number of files in `collect` folder, and then I will send a file every minute.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. What happens when you run your code? What did you expect to happen instead?

Comment: @Robert I have a struct Project that contains a folder named collect. Each file represents a string.I want to calculate the number of files in collect folder, and then I will send a file every minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use Apache camel with file2 component.
http://camel.apache.org/file2.html

Please read about 'noop' option before running any tests.
Processed files are deleted by default as far as I remember.

Update - simple example added:

1. I would recommend to start with https://start.spring.io/
2. Add at least two dependencies: Web and Camel (requires Spring Boot >=1.4.0.RELEASE and <2.0.0.M1)
3. Create new route, you can start from this example:

   ```
   @Component
   public class FileRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {
       public static final String DESTINATION = "file://out/";
       public static final String SOURCE = "file://in/?noop=true";

       @Override
       public void configure() throws Exception {
           from(SOURCE)
                   .process(exchange -> {
                       //your processing here
                   })
                   .log("File: ${file:name} has been sent to: " + DESTINATION)
                   .to(DESTINATION);
       }
   }
   ```
4. My output:

   - 2018-03-22 15:24:08.917 File: test1.txt has been sent to: file://out/
   - 2018-03-22 15:24:08.931 File: test2.txt has been sent to: file://out/
   - 2018-03-22 15:24:08.933 File: test3.txt has been sent to: file://out/

Comment: Hi, I have added the supplement. Can you help me to solve the problem?